# How to perform conditional sum/mean for each row in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks something like this. I would like to sum/average values of each row by only selecting columns that meet a certain condition (e.g., <=500) while excluding the first column and values that equal to 0 and -1, and output it in a new column.

```
Student   Resp_1   Resp_2   Resp_3   Resp_4   Resp_5 
1         894      -1       324      -1       589 
2         -1       -1       548      841      0 
3         285      216      -1       986      0
```

I have tried excluding the first column and columns that equal to -1 and 0 but the output values are based on the number of occurrences.

```
df$Sums <- rowSumns(df[-1] != "-1" & df[-1] != "0")
df$Means <- rowMeans(df[-1] != "-1" & df[-1] != "0")
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Student   Resp_1   Resp_2   Resp_3   Resp_4   Resp_5   Sums   Means
1         894      -1       324      -1       589      1807   602
2         -1       -1       548      841      0        1389   695
3         285      216      -1       986      0        1487   496
```

but instead it gives me:

```
Student   Resp_1   Resp_2   Resp_3   Resp_4   Resp_5   Sums   Means
1         894      -1       324      -1       589      3      1
2         -1       -1       548      841      0        2      1
3         285      216      -1       986      0        3      1
```

Answer (score 1):

We may need to `replace` the values to NA and then get the `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
newDF <- replace(df1[-1], df1[-1] == -1 |df1[-1] == 0, NA)
df1$Sums <- rowSums(newDF, na.rm = TRUE)
df1$Means <- rowMeans(newDF, na.rm = TRUE)
df1
#  Student Resp_1 Resp_2 Resp_3 Resp_4 Resp_5 Sums    Means
#1       1    894     -1    324     -1    589 1807 602.3333
#2       2     -1     -1    548    841      0 1389 694.5000
#3       3    285    216     -1    986      0 1487 495.6667
```

NOTE: If we need the `round`ed values for 'Means', use `round(rowMeans(..`

---

In the OP's code, the `rowSums` is taken on a logical `matrix` that have only TRUE/FALSE or 1/0 values

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Student = 1:3, Resp_1 = c(894L, -1L, 285L), Resp_2 = c(-1L, 
-1L, 216L), Resp_3 = c(324L, 548L, -1L), Resp_4 = c(-1L, 841L, 
986L), Resp_5 = c(589L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I only wanna select values that are >= 500?

Comment: @thesiobak  In that case change the condition from `== -1 | df[-1] == 0` to `df[-1] >=500`